# Concatenate thousands of files using EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, concatenation, emr

I currently have a process which reads files from AWS S3 and concatenates them using EMR. 
The input files have the following format: 1 header row and 1 data row.
Fields are comma-separated and wrapped in double-quotes.

Example:
"header-field1","header-field2","header-field3",...
"data-field1","data-field2","data-field3",...

The files vary in size between 90 and 200 bytes.

The output file has the following format:
"header-field1","header-field2","header-field3",...
"file1-data-field1","file1-data-field2","file1-data-field3",...
"file2-data-field1","file2-data-field2","file2-data-field3",...
"file3-data-field1","file3-data-field2","file3-data-field3",...
....

My current approach uses a default mapper and a single reducer to concatenate all the data rows and prepend 1 header row at the top of the final output file.
Because I want to have a single header row in the output final, I was forced to use only 1 single reducer in my EMR job. This I feel, drastically increases run-time.

Early tests ran great with tens of files. 
However, I am trying to scale this application to run for thousands of files with the final goal of concatenating 1 million.

My current process for 1000 files is still running after 30+ minutes, which is too long.
Do you have any suggestions on where I can improve my application to dramatically improve overall performance?

thank you.

Comment: Load it into Amazon Redshift and then UNLOAD the table

Comment: what sort of a cluster are your running this on? different core/master/slave configurations provide hugely different results.

Comment: After having tried numerous different cluster configurations under EMR, I came across this article: http://snowplowanalytics.com/blog/2013/05/30/dealing-with-hadoops-small-files-problem/

Comment: The small files I was taking as input overloaded the cluster's heap and severely impaired its performance. Reducing the number of input files and increasing their sizes fixed the problem.